# How to convert existing function to TermsQuery.builder

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

How to convert the following interface to latest TermsQuery.builder

https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.elasticsearch/elasticsearch/7.2.0/org/elasticsearch/index/query/QueryBuilders.html#termsQuery(java.lang.String,java.util.Collection). Existing code is given below

```
    List<String> ids;

    TermsQueryBuilder idsQb = QueryBuilders.termsQuery("id", ids);
    NativeSearchQuery query = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
            .withSourceFilter(new FetchSourceFilterBuilder()
            .withPageable(pageable).withQuery(idsQb).build();

    SearchHits<Profile> searchHits = esRestTemplate.search(query, Profile.class);
```

I am trying to convert the above function to the following interface

```
https://javadoc.io/doc/co.elastic.clients/elasticsearch-java/latest/co/elastic/clients/elasticsearch/_types/query_dsl/TermsQuery.Builder.html
```

I don't see a way to pass a List of ids to this function

```
https://javadoc.io/static/co.elastic.clients/elasticsearch-java/8.7.1/co/elastic/clients/elasticsearch/_types/query_dsl/QueryBuilders.html#terms(java.util.function.Function)
```

Comment: What's you current version and target version ?

Answer (score 0):

Did not run it, but this should be it:

```java
import co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch._types.query_dsl.QueryBuilders;

QueryBuilders
  .terms()
  .field("id")
  .terms(termsBuilder -> termsBuilder
    .value(
      ids.stream()
         .map(FieldValue::of)
         .collect(Collectors.toList())));
```